# center radio buttons around div but outside

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Can I somehow center radio buttons outside of a div and at the same time outside body width?

```
<body>
<div class='container'>
<div class='box'>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="points" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="points" value="-1">
</form>
  <div class='middle'>just a div</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I would preferably use some kind of css to display them left and right of the div.

[image]

I have created a fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/qhatn0a8/

I have tried using css left: -100px; but how to use css right on the other button?

Comment: If your div is "just a div" why not actually put it between the radio buttons?

Comment: Not sure what you want centered and in relation to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had to read twice to understand the result expected.

You may use position:relative & absolute. But in any case you should use `label` (and its attribute `for` ) so each input is link with its text description.

The idea about position is to wrap both input and text inside a label:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.box {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position:relative;/* added for absolute labels */
  /* height removed , seems not needed here */
}

.middle {
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
label {/* use coordonate so no need to size them */
  position:absolute;
  right:100%;
  margin:0 1em;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
label + label {
  right:auto;
  left:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='box'>
      <form>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="points" value="1">point1</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="points" value="-1">point2</label>
      </form>
      <div class='middle'>just a div</div>
    </div>
    <div class='box'>
      <form>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="points" value="1">point1</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="points" value="-1">point2</label>
      </form>
      <div class='middle'>just a div</div>
    </div>
    <div class='box'>
      <form>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="points" value="1">any text for point1</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="points" value="-1">point2</label>
      </form>
      <div class='middle'>just a div</div>
    </div>
    <div class='box'>
      <form>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="points" value="1">point1</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="points" value="-1">point2 or any text</label>
      </form>
      <div class='middle'>just a div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

note: buttons and text can go over other contents aside or go off the screen since, in absolute position, they are off the flow ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/qhatn0a8/3/

Comment: Perfect solution! Sorry for explaining bad. Don't drink and SO!

Comment: May I ask you how to also center vertical of the div box? If the height of the box is as in example https://jsfiddle.net/qhatn0a8/3/

edit: nvm, margin-top: 50%; solves that

Answer (score 0):

add label around your input, then add the css to them.

form position: relative, input absoulte;

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.box {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: auto;
}
.middle {
  background-color: red;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.box label:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  right:100%;
  margin-right:10px;
}
.box label:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%
}
.box form {
  position: relative;
}
label{
  white-space:nowrap;
    margin: 1%
  }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'>
    <form>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="points" value="1">point1</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="points" value="-1">point2
        <br>
      </label>
    </form>
    <div class='middle'>just a div</div>
  </div>
```